# Craft equivalent to EE snippets for use in templates?

Tags: templating

I am new to Craft from EE. I have a snippet of code which I will be reusing in several templates. I see Globals but that doesn't seem like like what I am looking for. What is the proper method of doing this within Craft? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Craft uses Twig, and Twig uses [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) for reusing snippets of code within templates.

In your macro file (for instance, macro/userMacro.html), you can create a macro:

```
{% macro hairColor(user) %}
    <span class="hair-{{ user.hairColor }}">{{ user.hairColor }}</span>
{% endmacro %}
```

Then, in any other file (or in your main _layout template, for that matter), you can import and use this macro:

```
{% import "macro/userMacro" as userMacro %}

{% for user in craft.users %}
    {{ userMacro.hairColor }}
{% endfor %}
```

Place your `import`-tag at the top of your _layout file, and you will be able to use it in every template that extends it (or is included by it).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where should I create the macros directory, within craft/templates directory?

Comment: Yes, within your templates folder. You can name it anything you want, though.

Comment: Okay perfect. Trying to wrap my head around this. I got an example working pretty quickly. Because I won't have many macro's, does it make sense to just have a single global macros file versus one for each snippet/macro?

Comment: For example, this is a reusable subnavigation. I just need t o pass it an entry's url. I got it working passing the entire entry but couldn't figure out just sending the entry.url.

Comment: I always have all related macros in one file. A user macro file, an image macro file and a forms macro file for example.

Comment: {{ navigationMacro.subnavigation(entry.url) }}

Comment: Perfect! I think I understand. I have a properties macro file, import as propertyMacros in _layout and use the propertyMacros.subnav(entry). Thank you so much! My only remaining question is can I send just entry.url as a param instead of the entire entry? Or is it irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, you can. See the comment above yours ;)

Comment: Awesome! I missed that. Got it working. Thanks for your time and help Paul!

Comment: Done and done :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

Create a file, for my purpose i created a file in

```
_includes/somefile.html
```

Then in my templates, I reuse the code in somefile.html by using

```
{{ include("_includes/somefile") }}
```